# "Could not update; currently locked" Error caused by VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have inherited and MS Access application. There are many issues that could be changed within the application but unfortunately it was rushed to production and major redesign changes cannot be made.

I have split and given FEs to 6 different users. for the most part there does not seem to be many issues with this, however some users are getting the error "Could not update; currently locked" intermittently when they create a new record on one of the forms and enter into a subform to insert information into it. The main form contains a customers details and the subform contains information on the product that they have.

Optimistic locking being used throughout the application and this doesn't seem to be occurring because two users are updating a single record, as they will basically never being looking at the same records.

I think that the issue may be code that is being used to generate that customer ID. The form where the error occurs is (1_1)Customer Subform. There is a subform within that subform called (1_1_1)Product Subform. These are linked by a PID, which is present in each subform. When the mouse is clicked within the product subform, the application hangs for a few seconds before giving the error "Could not update; currently locked".

There is a button on the form that does the following:

```vb
Private Sub NewCustomerRecord_Click()

DoCmd.Close acForm, "1Main_IPCOR"
DoCmd.OpenForm "1Main_IPCOR", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

Forms![1Main_IPCOR]![1IPCOR_Sform]![(1_1)Customer Subform].SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

Forms![1Main_IPCOR]![1IPCOR_Sform]![CREATED_DATE] = Now()

Forms![1Main_IPCOR]![1IPCOR_Sform]![P_ID] = NewP_ID()
Forms![1Main_IPCOR]![1IPCOR_Sform].Form.Refresh

Exit_New_record_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_New_record_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_New_record_Click
End Sub


Private Function NewP_ID() As String
Dim strTemplate As String

strTemplate = Replace("CUSXX", "XX", Right(Year(Date), 2))
NewP_ID = Nz(DMax(Expr:="Right([P_ID], 5)", _
                Domain:="[(1_1)_Customer]", _
                Criteria:="[P_ID] Like '" & strTemplate & "*'"), "0")
NewP_ID = strTemplate & Format(Val(NewP_ID) + 1, "00000")
    'Exit function now after successful incrementing or after error message

Exit_P_ID:
Exit Function

   'If an error occurred, display a message, then go to Exit statement
P_ID_Err:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error$

    Resume Exit_P_ID
End Function
```

What the function is doing is closing the main form and reopening it with a new ID so a new customer can be added.

Is there anything within the method that may be causing the record to be locked, and never unlocked?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be much simpler just to create a new record. Why close and reopen? I've never seen that.

Comment: I didn't write this code, so I'm going off the previous developer on this, but I asked the same question. That was how it was originally working. This form has a huge amount of dropdown lists on it, each of them will be filled in every time. After the database was split, they found that after you entered one record you were very close to hitting the limit of the amount of open tables allowed and would receive the error "cannot open any more databases", which caused a large amount of issues. So they wrote this function to invisibly close and reopen the form to close those connections.

Comment: If there is a simpler way to close off all the previous connections and just generate a new record, then that would be an ideal way to handle this.

Comment: There certainly is, but modifying an application out of context is way too broad for this forum. To be honest, it sounds like a several-days paid job for a skilled developer.

Comment: I understand that. I was just explaining the reasoning for the function, not looking for a way to it to be changed. I'm really just looking to see if there is anything in the function that would be locking the record to rule out this function as the reason for the error.

Comment: Created_Date  could possibly use textbox DefaultValue property set to Now() instead of code to populate. Have you confirmed that Refresh actually commits record to table? A better approach may be: `If Me.1IPCOR_Sform.Form.Dirty Then Me.1IPCOR_Sform.Form.Dirty = False`

Comment: Thank you I'll have a look at this tomorrow, but the refresh seems to be inaerting the record, yes.

Comment: I don't see any issues with this code related to locking. I would check other places. First of all, check that all opened recordsets are properly closed even in case of errors. The problem with too many open connections may be related to not closed recordsets